# How to integrate an exact differential?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

Question: Integrate $dg = (3x^2/y^2)dx - (2x^3/y^3)dy$ about the path ACB and show your answer in $x_1$, $x_2$, $y_1$, and $y_2$. [image]

My effort:

I let $dg = 0$ and solve it as an exact differential equation and got $2x^3/y^2 - 2x^3/y = C$. But after that, what should I do?

I know maybe is question is too easy, I apologize for that. Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: @runway44 Oh right, my direction is completely wrong then...

Comment: The question doesn't make much sense to me: what exactly does "from $\;x_1\;$ to $\;x_2\;$ and from $\;y_1\;$ to $\;y_2\;$" mean?!  Perhaps it is asking about the line integral of $\;dg\;$ from $\;(x_1,y_1)\;$ to $\;(x_2,y_2)\;$ ?

Comment: @DonAntonio Yes the question has a graph, but I don't know how to add it here

Comment: My original comment was made before I fully read the question, sorry. If you can't figure out how to copy-paste / take a photo and upload, then you can try to describe the picture. Does it just have a line segment from a point $(x_1,y_1)$ to another point $(x_2,y_2)$?

Comment: @DonAntonio Thank you, I guess i need to look up what line integral is.

Comment: @runway44 Thank you so much for your help and time! Its actually a square maybe? Thank you!

Comment: The integral along the path ACB is the sum of the integrals along the paths AC and CB. Along the first path AC we have ${\rm d}x=0$ and along the second path CB we have ${\rm d}y=0$. So the integral along the first path is $\int_{y_1}^{y_2} -2x_1^3/y^3\,{\rm d}y$ and the integral along the second path is $\int_{x_1}^{x_2} 3x^2/y_2^2\,{\rm d}x$.

Comment: @runway44 I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meaning of $\;dg = (3x^2/y^2)dx - (2x^3/y^3)dy\;$  is that the right hand is the gradient of a function $\;g\;$ that you have to find. How do we know that? Because

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(-\frac{2x^3}{y^3}\right)=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{3x^2}{y^2}\right)=-\frac{6x^2}{y^3}$$

Thus, find out your function $\;g\;$ . It must fulfill

$$g'_x=\frac{3x^2}{y^2}\stackrel{\text{integration}}\implies g=\frac{x^3}{y^2}+C(y)\;\text{( this last is a constant wrt x)}\;\implies$$

$$g'_y=-\frac{2x^3}{y^3}+C'(y)\stackrel{\text{It must be}}=-\frac{2x^3}{y^3}\implies C'(y)=0\implies C(y)=K=\text{constant}$$

and thus the scalar function $\;g(x,y)=\cfrac{x^3}{y^2}+K\;$ fulfills

$$\nabla g:=\left(g'_x,\,g'_x\right)=\left(\frac{3x^2}{y^2}\,,\;-\frac{2x^3}{y^3}\right)$$

and thus integration is just (Fundamental Theorem of Line Integrals, which is almost the usual FTC)

$$\int_{(x_1,y_1)}^{x_2,y_2)}(3x^2/y^2)dx - (2x^3/y^3)dy=g(x_2,y_2)-g(x_1,y_1)$$

(Observe the constant $\;K\;$ dissapears, as it happens in usual Riemann integral)

Comment: Thank you will try